# Can't pick custom folder?

Tags: settings, pantheon-files, folder

[image: http://imgur.com/yOzDWM9]

Under System Settings > Desktop, when I click "Custom" in the dropdown box, I get the above window to pick a folder. But I can't seem to choose anything! There is no "open" button. I can't even exit the selection screen. Am i missing something or is this a major bug?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that this was because I edited the GTK settings (org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings).

Resetting the schema solved the issue.